# Create SEO-friendly URL from php using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a problem where my site url is as below;

```
myhomesite.ext/listino/macchine/listino/marca.php?marca=Audi
```

and I want to obtain an url similar as follows

```
myhomesite.ext/listino/macchine/listino/marca-Audi/
```

So, I try with the following code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
</IfModule>


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^marca/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ marca.php?marca=$1
</IfModule>
```

but nothing happened, I don't understand and please point me out where is my mistake.

This is my latest add from the comment

Oh yes it's correct i am trying several solutions, but now i 've tried this code from one generator tool it's

```
 Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule marca/marca/(.*)/ marca.php?marca=$1 
RewriteRule marca/marca/(.*) marca.php?marca=$1
```

if i go on mediasportweb.com/macchine/listino/marca/marca/15 i find the url, with many problem on page on the css style, but i find it, but i also find the url mediasportweb.com/macchine/listino/marca.php?marca=15, i think that directive rewrite url erase the old url, what is wrong in my think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place this rule in `/macchine/listino/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /macchine/listino/

RewriteCond /marca\.php\?marca=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ marca/marca/%1? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule marca/marca/([^/]+)/?$ marca.php?marca=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

For css/js etc use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.

You can try adding this in your page's HTML header: `<base href="/" />`

Comment: I don't see any text after `look here`. Did you leave your comment incomplete?

Comment: oh i am sorry is the link where i am trying but http://mediasportweb.com/macchine/listino/marca.php?marca=5  i 've also tryed whith mod rewrite generation here http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/index.php but nothing, no solution ....i don't understand.

Comment: Question says php file link is `/listino/macchine/listino/marca.php?marca=Audi` but your comment says: `/macchine/listino/marca.php?marca=5` which one is correct?

Comment: Oh yes it's correct i am trying several solutions, but now i 've tried this code from one generator tool it's  Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule marca/marca/(.*)/ marca.php?marca=$1
RewriteRule marca/marca/(.*) marca.php?marca=$1   if i go on http://mediasportweb.com/macchine/listino/marca/marca/15/ i find the  url, with many problem on page on the css style, but i find it, but i also find the url http://mediasportweb.com/macchine/listino/marca.php?marca=15, i think that directive rewrite url erase the old url, what is wrong in my think?

Comment: Difficult to read code from comments. Edit your question and paste this working code so that I can suggest something.

Comment: ok i am agree with you, but  i am reading that the right solution for the url seo , is REDIRECT and not RewriteRule it 's correct?

Comment: This is the problem it is a file php, if i use rewrite i have two file and i must to avoid duplication, and i don't know what i must do...i can try with redirect but all examples on the web of this case says to use rewriterule, i have a little confusion in this moment...

Comment: see latest code in my answer for for SEO duplicate URL removal.

Comment: Abybhava latest question you say <base href="/" /> ? because i thinked  to put in the code rel canonical url with the ......macchina/listino/marca/marca , was wrong?

Comment: I would suggest using absolute URLs for css/js/images but if for some reason you cannot then use `<base href="/" />`

Answer (score 0):

Note that the url you shoud obtain from your code is:

```
myhomesite.ext/macchine/listino/marca/Audi/
```

and not:

```
myhomesite.ext/macchine/listino/marca-Audi/
```

Comment: yes it's ok, you ve reason,  but  i don't obtain nothing...if i  write myhomesite.ext/macchine/listino/marca.php?marca=Audi , i have no rewrite of url, why?

Comment: @FabrizioAntani The RewriteRule isn't expected to show you 'myhomesite.ext/macchine/listino/marca/Audi/' when you type 'myhomesite.ext/macchine/listino/marca.php?marca=Audi'. The rule will just let your PHP page read the $_GET parameters in the clean url the same way it does with the messy url. So to get your page you shoud go to 'myhomesite.ext/macchine/listino/marca/Audi/'

Comment: ok i am agree with you, but  i am reading that the right solution for the url seo , is REDIRECT and not RewriteRule it 's correct?

Answer (score 0):

How about changing to

```
RewriteRule ^marca\-([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ marca.php?marca=$1
```

from

```
RewriteRule ^marca/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ marca.php?marca=$1
```

Comment: nothing. i 've forgot that it is not the main directory .  but a sub called listino